# Why are combinatorial games called combinatorial?

Tags: terminology, combinatorial-game-theory

From Aaron Siegel's [Combinatorial Game Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-146):

> Combinatorial games are two-player games with no hidden information and no chance elements.

Why are those games (and the whole field) called "combinatorial"?

**EDIT:** What is combinatorial in those games? Is it the number of positions? The number of possible actions?

Comment: Doesn't the book explain it in the prequel/introduction?

Comment: Because early examples were analysed like finite game trees, etc. So combinatorial methods, essentially.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, it says that one of the goals of CGT is to understanding of the general **combinatorial** structure of games.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm not in a position to check/write a full answer this second (maybe tonight), but if I recall correctly, the book *does not* fully explain it in the beginning. And I disagree with your proposed explanation of "combinatorial methods were used".

Comment: So the question is what happens when we *combine* games. E.g. game addition is a prominent example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Main answer

> What is combinatorial in those games? Is it the number of positions? The number of possible actions?

The game position/state is, or can be, combinatorial in that it's a *combination* of other positions/states.

When studying combinatorial games, we typically study games that are built as a combination of other game components. For example, towards the end of a game of [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)), different isolated regions of the board are often independent (or nearly so), and so it can be considered as a combination of smaller games. In general, "Two-player games with no hidden information and no chance elements" can be easily combined to form a larger game with operations like the [(disjunctive) sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sum).

---

## History

I have not been able to track down the precise origin of the phrase "combinatorial game", but I do have some context that may help.

In 1966, Smith wrote a foundational paper in the first issue of the Journal of Combinatorial Theory called "[Graphs and Composite Games](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021980066800054)" extending the Sprague-Grundy theory to games played on a finite digraph (which may have infinite lines of play). In it, he writes:

> A *compound* or *composite* game may be defined as follows. We imagine that Abe and Barbara play simultaneously a number of impartial *component* games, $\mathscr{G}^1,\mathscr{G}^2,\ldots,\mathscr{G}^m$. Each player in turn (legally) makes a move in some or all of the components...

I think some of the earliest papers to use the exact phrase "combinatorial game" might be ones by A. S. Fraenkel in the mid 70s. For example, "Constructions in combinatorial games with cycles" by Fraenkel and Perl from [Volume 2 of "Infinite and Finite Sets - To Paul Erdös on His 60th Birthday"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Infinite_and_Finite_Sets/BNHuAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) and "Combinatorial games with an annihilation rule" by Fraenkel in ["The Influence of Computing on Mathematical Research and Education", Volume 20 of "Proceedings of Symposia in Applied Mathematics"](http://www.ams.org/books/psapm/020/). In the latter, he refers to the "disjunctive compound" (as did Smith) and the "contrajunctive compound".

**Edit:** Aaron Siegel has kindly pointed out that [On a combinatorial game](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316573900058) by Erdős and Selfridge in 1970 predates Fraenkel.

It seems that while the different *types* of compounds were discussed at least as far back as 1953 in [Milnor's "Sums of Positional Games"](https://princetonup.degruyter.com/view/book/9781400881970/10.1515/9781400881970-017.xml), perhaps the name for the games themselves evolved from "compound game" and "composite game" to "combinatorial game" (by Erdős?).

Answer (score 2):

Each position in a combinatorial game is one of the possible states of the 'board', given the 'pieces' and their 'rules', i.e. a combination. The game usually involves moving from one state to another via a 'move', with a defined state of 'win'.

Comment: To make sure I understand, are you claiming that "combinatorial" comes from the combination of "pieces" and "rules"? If so, do you have any evidence for that? If not, can you clarify what you meant by "i.e. a combination"?

Comment: It's not the only use of 'combinatorial' in Maths, for example [combinatorial design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design). Simple combinations just involve numbers, but they can involve any mathematical structure.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear in my comment. I'm well aware that "combinatorial" has a variety of uses in maths; in fact, I speak of combinations of non-numbers in my answer to this very question. I'm asking "Are you making the claim that people who study combinatorial games call them that (or first called them that) because of the combination of pieces and rules that make a game position? And if so, can you support that with evidence?" Given my answer to this question, I would be curious to know if there's an avenue of evidence/discussion I missed that leads to something like your conclusion.

Comment: Not an expert in the History aspect, but MW says the first use of 'combinatorial' was in 1818: https://www.merriam-webster.com/time-traveler/1818